# Passing credentials from Numara Footprints

Tags: webforms

I have a custom WebForms application that is utilized for our helpdesk that does some CRUD on a database of our satellite sites and their networking equipment.

I want to be able to integrate this with Numara Footprints, as we utilize it for our ticket tracking.

I have a template setup, and a working URL for a button control, but I need to know how to have my application detect a Footprints session and utilize the credentials.

I'm thinking that this is something that I'm going to need to ask Numara, but I figured I'd give you guys a shot first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have setup numerous web forms to interact with Numara Footprints (BMC).  You will have to create a cgi script on your Numara server.  Then you have to do is use that link as the Form Action in your HTML file.

Here's an example of one I have used:

```
form action="https://your-server.com/cgi-bin/your-service-desk/general/submit.pl" method="post
```

You can even use hidden fields to give you control of the redirects and timeouts of your redirects.

```
input type="hidden" name="redirecturl" value="http://www.your-server.com/new-form.html"
```

You can use a form element like this in your HTML:

```
input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text"
```

I hope this helps.